# How to Apply Aritstic effect to images and methods used to achieve it?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I am a newbie and i would like to give artistic effects to the images such as photocopy , blur ,glow edge, mosaic bubble ,pencil sketch ,marker , glass effect,paint brush,glow diffused effect programatically?

I want to implement it and any input is appreciated.
The following link depicts what i want to do exactly...

http://picasaweb.google.com/ashish.j.soni/BloggerPictures?authkey=Gv1sRgCMPHzP2P_fjRlgE#5413931800038472178

Answer (score 1):

I believe that these effects are implemented in the GIMP.

The source code is available online http://www.gimp.org/source/ This may help you see how such algorithms are implemented.

Comment: I came to know that convolution filter matrix can help me , but how to generate such filter ??

Comment: Take a look at the different convolution matrices here http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~kotowski/Grafika/Images/Index.html

Also it's probably worth picking up a copy of Digital Image Processing 3rd edition http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Image-Processing-Rafael-Gonzalez/dp/013168728X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1261129500&sr=8-1 although it's pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FullOpenCVWiki), it will make your life easier. It is aimed at real-time computer vision, Not really what you are after, but it has a lot of useful functionality (eg. opening/saving different image formats) and standard image operations.

Matlab/octave is also a good tool to get feeling with image processing algorithms.